# Use non-DHCP router's firewall on a DHCP router

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I have two routers, one from my ISP and the other one is a TP-Link router.
The DHCP server is enabled on my ISP one and its disabled on the TP-Link one.

I use the TP-Link's WiFi network as its more strong than my ISP router's one... However, I've some firewall rules on the TP-Link router and I want them to be applied on all the devices connected to the network.

Is it possible for the firewall rules to be on the TP-Link router but the internet to be on my ISP's provided router?

If yes, any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: Do you want wired Internet to pass through tp-link? (Since I assume you have done it for wifi users already)

Comment: @F.I.V - I think yes. I want the TP-Link router to get the internet from the router provided by my ISP so the firewall rules of the TP-Link modem gets applied.

Comment: So you may change the ISP modem to be bridge instead of NAT, then dial ppoe connection from the tp-link and use NAT service at tp-link instead. Your ISP may allow dialing additional pppoe (eg at tp-link) without changing the original ISP modem settings.

Comment: Do you have devices connecting directly to the ISP router, or are all devices connected only to the TP-Link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TP-Link router as your main router and the ISP router simply for the modem. If you enable DHCP on the TP-Link router, but use a different subnet (so instead of, eg. 192.168.1.XXX you would use 192.168.2.XXX) and connect all devices to the TP-Link router.

As @F.I.V commented, some routers will allow you to turn of NAT and simply use the ISP router as a modem, with the TP-Link essentially be connected directly to the internet. You would then enable NAT, DHCP and your firewall on the TP-Link, which will be your primary router.